# Keeping values through if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm trying to add multiple values that I acquire from multiple if statements. So I tried it out with just if statements and I get an error that the values totaltopFinal and totaltopFinal1 have not been initialized in the line of code 'overallCompletion = totaltopFinal + totaltopFinal1', when in fact they have values based upon the user input through the if statements.

Here is the section of code:

```
    while(t !=0){
        if(t == 30){
            //Loop for parameters of array
            System.out.println("What is the number of students taking the exam?");
            BufferedReader st = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String d = null;
            try {
                d =st.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            int s = Integer.parseInt(d);


            totalTop = thirtyMin[0] * s;
            totalTop1 = totalTop * constPercent[0];
            totalTop2 = thirtyMin[1] * s;
            totalTop3 = totalTop2 * constPercent[1];
            totalTop4 = thirtyMin[2] * s;
            totalTop5 = totalTop4 * constPercent[2];
            totalTop6 = thirtyMin[3] * s;
            totalTop7 = totalTop6 * constPercent[3];
            totalStudents = s + totalStudents;
            totaltopFinal = totalTop1 + totalTop3 + totalTop5 + totalTop7;

            averageTotal = totaltopFinal/totalStudents;
            x = Math.log(averageTotal);
            almostTotal = -21.6 * x;
            completeTotal = almostTotal + 156.8;

            System.out.println("The average of students who can take an exam in a hour is:" + completeTotal);
}
        if(t == 45){
            //Loop for parameters of array
            System.out.println("What is the number of students taking the exam?");
            BufferedReader st = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String d = null;
            try {
                d =st.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            int s = Integer.parseInt(d);


            totalTop = thirtyMin[0] * s;
            totalTop1 = totalTop * constPercent[0];
            totalTop2 = thirtyMin[1] * s;
            totalTop3 = totalTop2 * constPercent[1];
            totalTop4 = thirtyMin[2] * s;
            totalTop5 = totalTop4 * constPercent[2];
            totalTop6 = thirtyMin[3] * s;
            totalTop7 = totalTop6 * constPercent[3];
            totalStudents = s + totalStudents;
            totaltopFinal1 = totalTop1 + totalTop3 + totalTop5 + totalTop7;
}
        overallCompletion = totaltopFinal + totaltopFinal1;
}
```

Comment: where have you declared totaltopFinal and totaltopFinal1

Comment: I declared them at the beginning of the program. I just declared them as a double.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? In that case you should tag it with "homework".

Answer (score 0):

You can either initialize it in a `else` or initialize it while declaring:

```
double totaltopFinal = 0;
double totaltopFinal1 = 0;
```

If you don't, there's not guarantee that `t` would be 30 or 45, so `totaltopFinal` and `totaltopFinal1` might not get initialized as reported by the compiler.

Comment: Except I need a way to keep those values. Is there another way I could code it so that after each input and math process it keeps those values so I could then use all those valus to calculate the complete total?

Comment: I don't think I get what you said, but how about just storing them in temporary variables instead?

Comment: Can I call upon those after the if statement?

Answer (score 0):

First of I'd personally reformulate these if blocks to a "switch" block, which makes it slightly more readable.

That being said the reason for the exception you get is exactly as Ziya Wei has mentioned: "the compiler has no way of knowing whether or not your variable `t` will have such values that the conditions `(t==30)` and `(t==45)` will hold during execution of your program. That being the case there is no guarantee that the line `overallCompletion = totaltopFinal + totaltopFinal1;` can be calculated since variables `totaltopFinal` and `totaltopFinal1` have no existing values.

Try something like this:

```
double myVariable;
while(t!=0){
  switch(t){
    case(30): 
      // do stuff
      myVariable = X;
      break;
    case(45): 
      // do other stuff
      myVariable = Y;
      break;
    default: 
      // do fallback stuff (if necessary)
      myVariable = Z;
  }
  // do whatever you'd like to do with myVariable
}
```

Alternative this this would be to give an initial value before the loop as mentioned in the previous answer by Ziyao Wei. As a final comment, you might want to read up on variable scope/visibility to clear up some stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Java is rightly complaining that `totaltopFinal` and `totaltopFinal1` might not have been initialized at the point where you try to use them to compute `overallCompletion`. A possible solution could be to initialize them to some initial value (like 0) before your `while` loop.

Your code also has another problem. Suppose at the start of the loop `t` has a non-zero value different from 30 and 45: **your loop will never end!**

I suggest you carefully review what you're trying to achieve with that piece of code.